# product-archive.php not overridden in last version of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

In the previous version of `woocommerce` i overridden `product-archive.php` with no problem.But in the last version i can't do that.

all pages expect `product-archive.php` overriden.

Also in the `woocommerce/status` i can't see `product-archive.php` name in the overridden list. but other pages is done.

[image]

FYI i'm not using `Woocommerce.php` in the my theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't the file your trying to overwrite archive-product.php, not product-archive.php?